# Post a link to wall of Facebook page using Facebook sdk 3.1

Tags: android, facebook

How can I post a link on page's timeline/wall from Android application using Facebook sdk 3.1.

I have tried to post using pageid/feed. But it is shown under the label “Recent Posts By Others on pagename" even it is posted by the owner of the page. I need to show it on the wall of the page. Code used for posting on the page is as below

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("message","message");              
postParams.putString("name","name");
postParams.putString("link",link);
postParams.putString("picture",picture);
postParams.putString("display", "page");

Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {

public void onCompleted(Response response) {
    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                                                    if (error != null) {
    Log.e("FACEBOOK ERROR", ""+ error.getErrorMessage());
            } else {
                                                        JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                                                .getGraphObject()
                                                                .getInnerJSONObject();
                                                        String postId = null;
                                                        try {
                                                            postId = graphResponse
                                                                    .getString("id");
                                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                        }
                                                }
}
};

Request request = new Request(session,pageid+"/feed",postParams, HttpMethod.POST,callback);
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

Comment: How are you posting to the page, and what endpoint are you using as the path for the graph request? Have you read this doc on managing page posts - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#post_types

Comment: do you have the manage_pages permission?

Comment: Yes manage_page permission is there

Comment: @MingLi is this possible or not

Comment: I don't know, I've never tried it myself.

Comment: I got the answer.For posting to Page wall the session value should be null and add access_token of the page as a post parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posting to Page wall the session value should be null and add access_token of the page as a post parameter.

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("message","message");              
postParams.putString("name","name");
postParams.putString("link",link);
postParams.putString("picture",picture);
postParams.putString("access_token", pageaccessToken);

Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {

public void onCompleted(Response response) {
    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                                                    if (error != null) {
    Log.e("FACEBOOK ERROR", ""+ error.getErrorMessage());
            } else {
                                                        JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                                                .getGraphObject()
                                                                .getInnerJSONObject();
                                                        String postId = null;
                                                        try {
                                                            postId = graphResponse
                                                                    .getString("id");
                                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                        }
                                                }
}
};

Request request = new Request(null,pageid+"/feed",postParams, HttpMethod.POST,callback);
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

This guide shows you how to get started developing with the [Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

**Complete samples**

`HelloFacebookSample`: an all-round sample that demonstrates profile access, status updates and photo uploading

`Scrumptious`: demonstrates the use of login, requests, pickers, picture uploads, and Open Graph publishing